# Updating logistic regression model by adding a predictor in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have created a forward stepwise model `forward_stepwise = step(nullglm, scope=list(upper=fullglm), direction="forward", test="Chisq", trace=T)`

I wanted to add some interaction terms, I know I have to use `update` but I am unsure of the exact syntax.

Comment: do you have interactions in fullglm?

Comment: @SushiChef No, I just want to add new terms into the model without having to define it